# laravel legacy route url

Tags: php, laravel, legacy

i have 2 routes with POST methods

```
Route::post('/payment/checkOrder','Finance\PaymentCallbackController@checkOrder');
Route::post('/payment/paymentAviso', 'Finance\PaymentCallbackController@paymentAviso');
```

how can i create legacy links for these routes?

```
/plat.php?paysystem=5&method=checkOrder
/plat.php?paysystem=5&method=paymentAviso
```

Comment: `Route::post('/plat.php', ...);` then just get url parameters in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a single route that recieves a method string, and then call the desired functions according to it.

```
Route::post('/payment/{method}','Finance\PaymentCallbackController@handler');
// PaymentCallbackController.php 
public function handler(Request $request){
   // make sure to validate what methods get sent here
   $this->{$request->method}($request); 
   // use $this if its in this controller, for otherControllers 
   // try something with the looks of  app('App\Http\Controllers\OtherControllerController')->{$request->method}->($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this route:

```
Route::post('/plat.php', 'SomeController@action');
```

In your controller function:

```
// SomeController.php

public function someAction()
{
    $paysystem = $request->query('paysystem');
    $method = $request->query('method');
    // some logic here
    return view('something');
}
```

Comment: This is (unfortunately) really dependent on your web server and it's configuration.